# MVC4 (Web API) controller in SharePoint 2007 Virtual Directory Error: Access is Denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET 4 app that I have in a virtual directory in my SharePoint site. This is a self contained app in its own app pool so I don't think SP is the problem but?  The aspx page works fine, but a request to the ApiController returns 401 Error: Access is Deniend.

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Error: Access is Denied.</body></html>
```

Event Viewer has nothing and IIS log shows 401 2 2148074254 then 401 1 0 then 200 0 0 then 401 1 2148074248.  I Know that last 401.1 looks like my mistake, but I have confirmed many times it is the Last log entry for a request.  Consistant in IE8, Chrome, FireFox.

Fiddler shows only 401s, "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM" alternating with "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMblah_blah_blah..." and the HTML above.

Backup plan is to ditch the controller and use a .ashx, but hopefully SO can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around until the project is no longer in SharePoint.  Kept the Controler class (PSSController) as-is, but added an ashx file with the below code and changed the javascript to use it.  cntrl is just my class; your QueryString and Post params will be different.  A bit hacky but it works :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PipWebApp
{
    public partial class PSSurvey2API : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            String InputString = null;
            using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                InputString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            List<PSSurvey.cntrl> cntrls = (List<PSSurvey.cntrl>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(InputString, typeof(List<PSSurvey.cntrl>));
            String Params = context.Request.QueryString["Params"];


        Controllers.PSSController APICon = new Controllers.PSSController();

        if (context.Request.QueryString["Rpt"] == null)
            context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(APICon.Post(cntrls, Params)));
        else
            context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(APICon.Post(cntrls, context.Request.QueryString["Rpt"], Params)));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}